# is there a way to set the border and background color of a Flash ScrollPane component to transparent?

Tags: flash, scrollpane

I'm looking at [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/containers/ScrollPane.html#getStyleDefinition%28%29) documentation and am completely confused by what the hell they're saying. Does anyone have a simple example of modifying the style of a ScrollPane component to set the pane area to transparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this seems to do the trick:

create an empty movie clip and export it for action script. then on your scroll pane instance do this:

```
myScrollPane.setStyle( "upSkin", myEmptyMC );
```